# javascript regex split match at char once, not multiple

Tags: javascript, regex, split, match

Having the following example:

```
var s = '#hello \n##1234 \n #hello2';
var splits = s.split(/#[^##]/);
```

produces: `["", "ello ↵#", "234 ↵ ", "ello2"]`

But want it to produce: `["hello ↵##1234 ↵ ", "hello2"]`

How to match single occurrence of character (#) but NOT if its occurring multiple times, and also not the last occurrence of the multiple occurred one.

Comment: `[^##] == [^#]`

Comment: was not able to edit again: 
Shure I mean - Wanting: ["", "hello ↵##1234 ↵ ", "hello2"]

Comment: [^#]  produces: ["", "ello ↵#", "234 ↵ ", "ello2"] ~ so yes / [^##] == [^#] // but how to Exclude?

Answer (score 5):

With `split`, you would need a negative lookbehind to prevent matching `#` that comes after another `#`, but JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

Match the chunks rather than split with `.match(/(?:##+|[^#])+/g)` that will match 1 or more occurrences of 2+ `#` or any char other than `#`:

```js
var s = '#hello \n##1234 \n #hello2';
var splits = s.match(/(?:##+|[^#])+/g);
console.log(splits);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:##+|[^#])+` - 1 or more occurrences (`+`) of:

  - `##+` - 2 or more `#` symbols, as many as possible
  - `[^#]` - any character other than `#` (a `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any single char that is not inside the defined set/ranges).

**NOTE**: `[^##]` is the same as `[^#]`, you cannot negate a *sequence* with  a negated character class, only specific chars or ranges of chars.